# Cron Based Google Analytics API Requests using PHP

Tags: php, cron, google-analytics-api

After reading the GA API documentation and looking at the sample code for PHP, I'm unable to see how to authenticate without the user being present.

For our website, we want to pull GA Data in once an hour and compare with additional metrics on our site.  We aim to do this on a CRON which will then inform us of correlations between current site behaviour and historical GA trend data.

Is there a way to emulate the authentication in PHP so that these could be done via a CRON, assuming email and password are known for the GA account?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more?Do you want to authenticate into web app that requests GAPI reports? If so, maybe you can run CRON on certain page accessible only for local requests (with local ip)?

Comment: Hi Kane, I want to have an unattended (non-logged in) cron that starts, authenticates with GAPI, queries the GA account for specific metrics, such as page views between 2 time frames, returns the data, stores it in the database and then number crunches it.  I don't know how to make the initial connection and query parts. Once I can get the data, I can do the rest *I believe* :)

Comment: Can you maybe link the authentication documentation here?  I am sure that the answer to your question is in there :)

Comment: Yup sure - it says you have to be logged in: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/gdataGettingStarted.html for getting started, http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/reference.html for the reference for the api and http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/analytics/simple.php for sample code (that requires a user present, which I'm hoping can be done via curl or similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after a clarification i think i got what you mean. Following is a huge generalization.

So, i assume you're using some kind of a framework, but if no, it's not a problem anyway.
You can create separate php file on your public folder which will check from what ip we've requested it ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) if it's local (works fine in default Apache, some additional config required if you're using proxy server like nginx) then you can proceed to getting GA data.

How to get it described in here: http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

Pretty straightforward: include GAPI class and then run

```
$ga = new gapi('email@yourdomain.com','password');
$ga->requestReportData(145141242,array('browser','browserVersion'),array('pageviews','visits'));
```

---

If code above doesn't work, then you'll have to use OAuth2 to gain access to GA.

Description on how to do it:

1. General - [Core Reporting API - Authorization](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/gdataAuthorization.html)
2. General - [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)
3. [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2)

Comment: I'm checking this out now... - I thought the this class was obsolete! I'll report back in just a moment.

Comment: @MyStream, just checked when that class was last updated, by now it's probably won't work. Added links to Google docs describing process of using OAuth2 to get an access to GA.

Comment: Hi Kane,  I was unsuccessful with the OAuth2 way without a user being present.  But the way you've described about DOES work.  I was wrong in my assumption that it was deprecated.  However, trying to do it the OAuth2 way unattended would be nice if anyone can contribute code to that end?  I'm accepting your answer and hope others can extend for OAuth2.  Thanks!

Comment: @MyStream, good that it works. I too probably will have to deal with php accessing GA data, so probably will write about the way to do it some time later.

Comment: I'd be keen to see and contribute to your solution if you post it online or on GitHub or want any contributions - let me know? =) thanks!

Comment: I don't think the gapi() method works anymore due to two factor auth changes.  When I try to authenticate I get the error described here http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/03/best-practices-for-user-authentication.html